# Android 6.0.1 Not getting Location after getting permission at run time

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am working on google maps and Getting location using Fused Location API. Every thing is working fine as expected. I have a device having version 6.0

My code was working good. But now after software updates And I think its now 6.0.1, my code is not working , but its working on below 6.0. My problem is as stated under:

**Problem:**
             I am checking permission at runtime and User has to Allow for Locations. On Denying I am simply getting out of activity as I think Location is necessary in my app business logic.  But when User allows location I am even not getting location. Here is how I am asking for permission

```
//Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (!isPlayServicesAvailable(this))
        return;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}
```

> and here I am listening for request approval

```
     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                    startLocationUpdates();

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
//                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                       mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                       Toast.makeText(GoogleMapsActivity.this, "To enable the function of this application please enable position information permission of the application from the setting screen of the terminal.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                       showRationaleDialog();
                    }
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

> Here is My StartLocationUpdate Method

```
   private void startLocationUpdates() {
        try {

            if (mGoogleMap != null)
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
            //Check whether setting of position information is valid before acquiring current position
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();

                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                            // Since the setting is valid, the current position is acquired
//                            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(GoogleMapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, GoogleMapsActivity.this);
//                            }

                            // check if the device has OS Marshmellow or greater than
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                                if (GoogleMapsActivity.this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && GoogleMapsActivity.this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                                } else {
                                    // get Location
                                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, GoogleMapsActivity.this);
                                }
                            } else {
                                // get Location
                                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, GoogleMapsActivity.this);
                            }


                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Since the setting is not valid, a dialog is displayed
                            try {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(GoogleMapsActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                            // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", " Exception while Starting Location >>> " + e.toString());
        }
    }


     protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
```

I do not understand What is the problem. But what I sorted out is the following:

1. On my device having marshmellow (I dont know before updating my device was it 6.0.0 or already 6.0.1) My code was workin, When user allows location permission I gets my location and my code draws pin on desired place.
2. Now Its not working, I dont know why. Either it is due to Updating my cell phone or I also updated the SDK. Updating any of these could have effect in my scenario??

> I Just wanted to know if any one faced the same problem of not receiving location updates after User Allow location services. Please help.

Comment: Post startLocationUpdates();

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: post this method please

Comment: ok I got you ...

Comment: did it ............check updated question

Comment: Send me your this class at zeeshansardar61@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154882/discussion-between-shararti-kaka-and-zeeshan-sardar).